# Random Generator max/min values?

Tags: java, random, methods

I have written a method variation:

```
private int variation() {
    int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(90);
    return (randomNumber + handicap)/18 - 2;
}
```

Assuming that the handicap is = 18, what are the minimum and maximum values that this method can return?

Comment: Is your calculator broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Maximum=3;

Minimum=-1.
```

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) for random

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0
>   (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

Therefore, the maximum returnable value of nextInt(90) is 89 and the minimum is 0.

Plugging into your function: 
(89 + 18)/18 - 2 = (Technically 3.94444444444 which is rounded down to 3)
(0+18)/18-1=-1